# Can't get "syntax on" to work in my gvim

Tags: syntax, vim

(I'm new to Linux and Vim, and I'm trying to learn Vim but I'm having some issues with it that I can't seen do fix)

I'm in a Linux installation (Ubuntu 8.04) that I can't update, using Vim 7.1.138.

My vim installation is in `/usr/share/vim/vim71/`. /home/user/

My .vimrc file is in `/home/user/.vimrc`, as follows:

```
fun! MySys()
    return "linux"
endfun

set runtimepath=~/.vim,$VIMRUTNTIME
source ~/.vim/.vimrc
```

And then, in my `/home/user/.vim/.vimrc`:

```
" =============== GENERAL CONFIG ==============
set nocompatible
syntax on

" =============== ENCODING AND FILE TYPES =====
set encoding=utf8
set ffs=unix,dos,mac

" =============== INDENTING ===================
set ai " Automatically set the indent of a new line (local to buffer)
set si " smartindent (local to buffer)

" =============== FONT ========================
" Set font according to system
if MySys() == "mac"
  set gfn=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono:h13
  set shell=/bin/bash
elseif MySys() == "windows"
  set gfn=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono:h10
elseif MySys() == "linux"
  set gfn=Inconsolata\ 14
  set shell=/bin/bash
endif

" =============== COLORS ======================
colorscheme molokai

" ============== PLUGINS ======================
" -------------- NERDTree ---------------------
:noremap ,n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" =============== DIRECTORIES =================
set backupdir=~/.backup/vim
set directory=~/.swap/vim
```

...fact is the command `syntax on` is not working, neither in vim or gvim. And the strange thing is: If I try to set the syntax using the gvim toolbat, **it works**. Then, in normal mode in gvim, after activating using the toolbar, using the code `:syntax off`, it works, and just after doing this trying to do `:syntax on` doesn't work!!

I have the syntax files in both `/usr/share/vim/vim71/` and home folders (in the home there's only a python syntax module). I've run `sudo aptitude install vim` as well and there's nothing do download, EXCEPT `vim-gtk`, since I was afraid of some kind of incompatibility.

What's going on? Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought about it, but in the end, this question could be in every trilogy site, since it could be a package problem in my Linux installation (better in serverfault) or a simple config in *programming* syntax that I'm getting wrong (stackoverflow). Since this is a configuration related o programming itself, I thought it would be better to post here in SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break this down into something simple.  Instead of trying to debug multiple possible points of failure (`source`, `runtimepath`), see if the simplest case works.  Then, add back in each piece until something breaks.

First of all, make sure your `~/.vimrc/` and `~/.vim/.vimrc` are checked into version control or save off a copy.  Also, unless you've modified the original python syntax module for some reason, there should be no need to have it located in your `~/.vim` directory.

Now, delete the contents of both `.vimrc` files and add only the following two lines to your `~/.vimrc` file.

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

Now, open up a new vim session with the file you're trying to syntax highlight.  Does it work?  I would expect this to work in most cases if the filetype is being detected properly.

```
:set filetype?
```

If the syntax highlighting isn't working and the `filetype` is correct there's something more wrong than just your `.vimrc` files.  You could try removing your ~/.vim directory too to see if that's the problem.

I'm not sure why you're setting your `runtimepath` but when I check mine, it shows `~/.vim` as the first entry (and there are a lot more directories than just `VIMRUNTIME`) by default so that line shouldn't be necessary.

```
:set runtimepath?
```

Also, `VIMRUNTIME` is misspelled.  I expect this is your problem.  If I use your `set runtimepath` from above, I lose syntax highlighting as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the mispelling. I'm really ashamed of it... at least I know you really read all my config to help me. :) The error is still strange since all the other configuration were working, except the syntax. And thanks for the suggestion of the simple case to test.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu default install doesn't install all of vim.

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `filetype plugin on` before `syntax on` in your .vimrc.